# undefined method instance_double for RSpec::Mocks::ExampleMethods

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, unit-testing, rspec, rspec-mocks

I have a test case like this:

```
describe WorkCardsController do
    it "something" do
        work_card = instance_double(WorkCard, {:started?=>true} )
        #some more code
    end
end
```

When I run RSpec, I get an error:

```
undefined method 'instance_double' for #<Rspec::Core::ExampleGroup::Nested_1::Nested_8::Nested_3:0x007f0788b98778>
```

According to http://rubydoc.info/github/rspec/rspec-mocks/RSpec/Mocks/ExampleMethods this method exists. So I tried to access it directly by:

```
describe WorkCardsController do
    it "something" do
        work_card = RSpec::Mocks::ExampleMethods::instance_double(WorkCard, {:started?=>true} )
        #some more code
    end
end
```

And then I got a very surprising error:

```
undefined method 'instance_double' for Rspec::Mocks::ExampleMEthods:Module
```

which is contrary to the documentation I linked above.

What am I missing?

Comment: Are you sure to have rspec3? The gem version in this moment is 2.14, hence if you haven't installed it by github, it's just normal that method doesn't exists.

Answer (score 3):

From the documentation you pointed to:

> Mix this in to your test context (such as a test framework base class) to use rspec-mocks with your test framework.

Try to `include` it into your code:

```
include RSpec::Mocks::ExampleMethods
```

Your direct approach failed, because calling

```
RSpec::Mocks::ExampleMethods::instance_double(...)
```

expects that the method was declared as a class method:

```
def self.instance_double(...)
```

but it has been declared as an instance method :

```
def instance_double(...)
```